# Destructor vs Overloading delete

Tags: c++, overloading, destructor

What exactly is the purpose of having both a destructor and Overloading `delete` for a class?

In what types of scenarios should one use both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you allocate an object with a `new` expression like:

```
X *x = new X();
```

It basically does two separate things: it allocates some memory, then creates an object in that memory, roughly equivalent to:

```
void *temp = operator new(sizeof(X));
X *x = new(temp) X;
```

The first just allocates a block of raw memory. The second just takes that block of raw memory, and creates an object in it.

Roughly the reverse happens when you delete an object:

```
delete x;
```

...is roughly equivalent to something like:

```
x->~X();
operator delete(static_cast<void *>(x));
```

So, operator new and operator delete *just* deal with allocating and freeing raw memory. The constructor and destructor *just* deal with creating and destroying objects *in* memory that's already been allocated. After the destructor runs to destroy the object in some memory, then `operator delete` is used to free the memory itself.

By default, there's one global pair of `operator new` and `operator delete` that are used to allocate objects of all types. You can replace those if you want. You can also provide an `operator new` and `operator delete` for a specific class (as static member functions<sup>1</sup>). In this case, those functions will be used only for managing memory for objects of that class. This tends to be particularly useful for things like classes that are extremely small, and you expect to allocate a large number of objects of this class. Many memory managers aren't particularly efficient when dealing with an extremely large number of extremely small items, so overloading in this case can improve (reduce) memory usage quite a bit.

There are also `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`, which are used when/if you allocate/free arrays of objects. `operator new[]` is just passed a number of bytes to allocate, and `operator delete` is just passed a block of raw memory to free. If you decided to overload these, you might presume that they'd be used primarily for larger blocks of memory and optimize appropriately, but that's about the only difference from the non-array versions.

As a rule, I'd avoid using `new` to allocate arrays (ever) rendering these entirely irrelevant. And no, they can't be/aren't used by an allocator if you create something like an `std::vector<T>` either. Well, I suppose if you didn't mind abusing the system quite thoroughly, you *could* create an allocator for use with `std::vector` that used `new char[size]` to manage the allocation, in which case it would use one of these, but I find it hard to imagine that anybody would really do that. Maybe at one time when C++ wasn't well understood, but nowadays it would stick out like a sore thumb in any decent code base.

---

<sup>1. One minor oddity: the compiler "knows" these must always be static, so even if you don't use the `static` key-word when you declare/define them, they'll be static anyway.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The answer becomes clear once you realize that constructor/destructor and new/delete pairs serve orthogonal purposes:

- Constructors and destructors let your class control the processes of acquisition and release of the resources that your class owns. These do not include the memory for the object itself.
- Operators `new` and `delete` let your class control the process of acquisition and release of the memory allocated to the instance of the class itself.

It is also important to realize that the invocations of `new` and `delete` bracket the invocations of constructors and destructors: `new` happens before the constructor, and `delete` happens after the destructor. While destructor may treat the content of the object as "live", operator `delete` must treat it as "dead"; in particular, trying to reference any of the members or call any member functions of the class from `delete` is undefined.

Now the answer should be clear: you implement one or the other, or both, depending on what your program wishes to control.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, a destructor is intended to implement class-specific behaviour such as deallocation of allocated resources and the like, while overloading the `delete` operator is intended for custom memory management which is not class-specific or does not target a class alone[as described here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete). Typically, there should not be a necessity to overload `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Destructor is used to destroy the instance of the class (the object) regardless of whether it is allocated on the stack as automatic variable, or on the heap with operator `new`.

Overloaded `new` and `delete` will only be used to allocate memory when the code uses operators `new` and `delete`.

Note that `new` and `delete` are static, and work with void (unstructured) memory. They cannot access members of the class through (implicit or explicit) `this`. You can cast this memory to your object and initialize/reset it, but they are not meant to be used for this.